# webstatic php71 config conflict

Tags: php, apache

i try install php 7.1 from webtatic repo over php 5.3 but every time i have rpm_check_debug error

```
-bash-4.1# yum install php71w -tvy --merge-conf --skip-broken
```

Run rpm_check_debug

> Error:   file /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf from install of
>   mod_php71w-7.1.1-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   php-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64

but /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf not modified after instalation.

any ideas?